# Javascript closures and Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have two files: BaseClass.js and DerivedClass.js. Contents as below

```
//---------------------BaseClass.js----------------------------

(function () {
    BaseClass= function() { };
    BaseClass.prototype.getTestVar = function() {
    return 'base test variable';
    };
})();


//----------------DerivedClass.js----------------------------

(function () {
    DerivedClass= function() { };
    DerivedClass.inherits(BaseClass);
    DerivedClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
    DerivedClass.prototype = {
        newvar : 'derived func variable ',
        getNewVar : function() { return this.newvar; }
    };
})();
```

---

In my html file 'test.html' I have the following

```
var dc = new DerivedClass();
alert(
    'The value in newvar of derived class ' + dc.getNewVar() + 
    ' base class variable ' + dc.getTestVar()
);
```

I get the Javascript error that dc.getTestVar() is not a function. 
Any help in solving this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using some kind of OOP library? Javascript functions don't have a built-in `inherits` method, to my knowledge…

Comment: Oh, is it [Crockford's OOP sugar](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html#sugar)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out these few lines:

```
DerivedClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
DerivedClass.prototype = {
    newvar : 'derived func variable ',
    getNewVar : function() { return this.newvar; }
};
```

First it assigns a new `BaseClass` as the prototype, but then the next line *overwrites* that prototype with a fresh object. Perhaps you need to assign `DerivedClass.prototype.newvar` and `DerivedClass.prototype.getNewVar` separately — assuming that falls in line with whatever classical inheritance library you're using that provides the `inherits` method.

That is,

```
DerivedClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
DerivedClass.prototype.newvar = 'derived func variable';
DerivedClass.prototype.getNewVar = function() { return this.newvar; }
```

Still, this seems like a mix of classical and prototypal inheritance. Consider reading up on the documentation of that classical inheritance library and see if there's a more consistent way of doing this sort of thing.

For example, if you're using [Crockford's classical inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) (a guess from the `inherits` keyword), this seems to be his intended way to declare a method:

```
DerivedClass.method('getNewVar', function () { return this.newvar });
```

Granted, that's *exactly* equivalent to what you're already doing, but, if we're gonna use his library, may as well use his style for consistency.

Comment: I answered the exact same thing at the exact same time. May the luckiest man win!

Comment: Haha, SO is funny that way ;) +1 to get you started!

Comment: Kind of you :-) I'm eagerly awaiting my 5000. +1

Answer (score 2):

At this point:

```
DerivedClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
DerivedClass.prototype = {
    newvar : 'derived func variable ',
    getNewVar : function() { return this.newvar; }
};
```

You're first setting the prototype to the `BaseClass`, but then overwriting it with a new object. Try this instead:

```
DerivedClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
DerivedClass.prototype.newvar = 'derived func variable ';
DerivedClass.prototype.getNewVar = function() { return this.newvar; };
```